# Comparing two strings to get element that fire event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue that I want to compare two strings to get info what button create event.

```
$(".buttonDay").click(function (event) {
  var day = document.getElementById('DayBtn1').id;
  var buttonId = event.target.id;
  if (day.localeCompare(buttonId)) {
    //do something
  }
});
```

Can anyone help me what I have to do?

Comment: you want to get the `id` of the `$(".buttonDay")` ?

Comment: This is an oxymoron in JS: `document.getElementById('DayBtn1').id;`

Comment: `..localeCompare(...)` returns an integer, your condition will only be true when `buttonId` comes after `day`. If you want to check if those strings are the same, use `==`.

Comment: What is it you actually trying to achieve? I don't know what exactly I'm looking at but would a simple `if(document.getElementById('DayBtn1') != event.target)` or similar not work.

Comment: @MehdiBouzidi yes  and I want to compare it with my 4 strings (id's of buttons) to get info what fire event

Comment: As a side note, don't name your event object `event` as that is the name of the default browser event object (In chrome anyway). It gets confusing quickly when you forget to specify `event` in your function params. With jQuery I use any other name but `event` for that reason.

Comment: Can you provide the relevant HTML to see exactly how these elements relate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that easy by comparing `day === buttonId`. Here is the basic example:

```js
$(".buttonDay").click(function (event) {
  var day = document.getElementById('DayBtn1').id;
  var buttonId = event.target.id;
  if (day === buttonId) {
    console.log("Correct target")
  } else {
    console.log("Incorrect target")
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="DayBtn1" class="buttonDay">Correct target</button>
<button id="DayBtn2" class="buttonDay">Incorrect target</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you use jQuery, you can use the `.is()` method:

```js
$(".buttonDay").click(function (e) {
    if ($("#DayBtn1").is(e.target)) {
        console.log("correct");
    } else {
        console.log("wrong");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="buttonDay">
    <button id="DayBtn1">1</button>
    <button id="DayBtn2">2</button>
</div>
```